# What is the meaning of "sanity" in "sanity check"?

Tags: meaning, ambiguity

The phrase "sanity check" comes up often in programming, *e.g.*

> It's a good *sanity check* before attempting to decrypt the key.

Usually, its context is one in which a commonly assumed state (*e.g.* no memory corruption) is being tested, explicitly. For a long time, I interpreted "sanity" as the state opposed to "insanity", *e.g.*

> It's a good *check to make sure we don't lose our minds* before attempting to decrypt the key.

Because of the many instances I'd spent hours, or *days*, debugging a mysterious bug, only to find the cause to be some uncommon state in the environment or data, this interpretation made sense to me; a *sanity check* would have *saved my sanity*.

But then I realized that "sanity" had a more canonical meaning: cleanness, *e.g.*

> It's a good *check for cleanness* before attempting to decrypt the key.

Which is the interpretation meant by the phrase, "sanity check"?

Comment: To make a *sanity check* is just a quirky idiomatic way of saying *make sure what we're doing (or what we're looking at) isn't completely **insane/ridiculous/obviously stupid***. It's not a direct reference to the sanity of the speaker (or his audience).

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Ah, yes, that's a much better wording for the interpretation I held for a long time. I'm still not convinced though. Could "sanity" in that phrase actually have meant "cleanness" when it was first used, but due to the word "sanity" being more popularly recognized as the opposite of "insanity", _adopted_ a new meaning?

Comment: It means a check that we or the situation are not insane. For example an "assert" is a form of sanity check.

Comment: @acheong87: I personally wouldn't use "sanity check" to refer to basic validation of input parameter formats, for example. But if it was in the context of, say, an input form for a car insurance quote, asking for the applicant's Date of Birth, I might call it a "sanity check" to make sure the value input didn't imply the applicant was over 120 years old!

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Oh, I was not aware that the phrase was used outside of programming, but now it makes much more sense, thank you. As I commented under Hellion's response, it appears I had a mistaken belief about the meaning of "sanity".

Comment: @MετάEd - Nice example.

Comment: When you get a working definition of sanity, please send it to the U.S. Congress. They're the ones who could benefit most.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I refer you to [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/sanity?s=t), where it states (eventually):

> Synonyms
>
> 1. reason, rationality, sensibleness, **reasonableness.**

(emphasis added.)

A sanity check is simply a test to confirm that we are asking, or being asked for, something that is within some defined bounds of reasonableness.

Comment: Ah, I see. It seems the word "sanity" _doesn't_ have anything to do with cleanness or pureness. I had always believed it _did_, thinking it to be a root of the word "sanitation". But it appears that that was exactly the culprit, looking at [the etymology of "sanitation"](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=sanitation).

Comment: @acheong87 But it does. The Latin *sanus*, which is the distant root of both words, means *healthy*.

Comment: @AndrewLeach - Yes, but I guess what I meant is that I _inferred_ the meaning of "sanity" _from_ "sanitation", which I incorrectly believed to mean "cleanliness" to begin with (as opposed to something to do with health). Had I had my premises straight and understood that _sanus_ means _healthy_, as you point out, I probably wouldn't have had this confusion.